# Login form for loding layer from MS SQL Server

Tags: qgis, sql, server

I created database and featureclass and table in SQL server. I loaded layer in QGIS, my UI editing and veiw from, designed by qt designer and saved to QGIS project.

Now I need to create login form: after opening QGIS, click 1 button and open this form and type user and password for connect to SQL server and load layer.

Comment: What is your question ?. Please be concise when you need people to help you.

Comment: who has done the same thing? Can anyone help me with this or introduce resource ?